# SharePoint online webpart target audience from SharePoint group

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, groups, audience-targeting

When trying to add SharePoint online web part with the target audience, I could not found SharePoint group?

How to set SP Group in the target audience?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint groups are not supported in audience targeting in SharePoint online.

> Azure AD groups (including security groups and Microsoft 365 groups) are supported with the exception of AAD dynamic groups.

**Documentation**: [Target content to a specific audience on a SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/target-content-to-a-specific-audience-on-a-sharepoint-site-68113d1b-be99-4d4c-a61c-73b087f48a81)

> Currently you can only use AD groups or Microsoft 365 groups to target audiences.

**Source**: [Audience Targeting for Quick Links Web Part in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/17/audience-targeting-for-quick-links-web-part-in-sharepoint-online/)

You can vote on below similar SharePoint UserVoice:

1. [Allow using SharePoint groups to target audiences in quick links web part](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/42712238-allow-using-sharepoint-groups-to-target-audiences)
2. [Navigation audience targeting support SharePoint groups](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/40584448-navigation-audience-targeting-support-sharepoint-g)

Comment: Any MS doc on this?

Comment: Check updated answer for similar threads & documentation

Comment: Hi @SamTimothy, does this answers your question? Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

Update about use of Azure AD Dynamic Groups:
MC302460: Use of Azure Active Directory Dynamic Groups now supported for SharePoint Online audience targeting